# CMS Read More script

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript running on my home page to provide a read more facility, so part of the content is hidden until the read more link is clicked.

This works well but I would like to use an image instead of text.. I have managed to do this initially, but if you click the image it is replaced with text again.

The code I use is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[function toggle() { var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
  ele.style.display = "none";
text.innerHTML = "Read More";
}
else {
ele.style.display = "block";
text.innerHTML = "Hide";
}
}
// ]]></script> 

<p><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();"><img alt="Reece Read More" src="/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/Readmore_sml.png" /></a></p>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this piece of code:

```
function toggle() {
 var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
 var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
 if(ele.style.display == "block") {
      ele.style.display = "none";
  text.innerHTML = "<img alt='Reece Read More' src='/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/Readmore_sml.png'>";
   }
 else {
  ele.style.display = "block";
  text.innerHTML = ""<img alt='Reece Hide' src='/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/Hide_sml.png'>"";
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that has cured one of my many headaches!!

Comment: Remember Vote Up the answer it was useful for you